# Proving something that resembles Fermat's Little Theorem

Tags: number-theory

This was one of the advanced level questions in our practice problems for number theory:

> Let $a$ be an integer greater than $1$ and let $p$ be an odd prime that is not a divisor of $a(a^2 − 1)$. Let $$n = \frac{a^{2p} − 1}{a^2 − 1}$$ 
>   Prove that $a^{n−1} ≡ 1 \text{(mod n)}$, by showing that $2p|(n − 1)$ and $a^{2p} ≡ 1 \text{(mod n)}$.

Edit: Thanks to an answer by Peter I see now that $n(a^2-1)=a^{2p}-1 \implies a^{2p}≡ 1\text{(mod n)}$

So I tried writing out n-1 as:
$$n-1=\frac{a^{2p} − 1}{a^2 − 1}-1 = \frac{a^{2p} − a^2}{a^2 − 1}$$

but then I couldn't see how to factor out a $2p$. I noticed that $2p$ might have something to do with the periodicity of the residues $\text{mod n}$ as long as $gcd(a,n)=1$. Is $2p$ the primitive root of n, i.e. does $2p =ord_n(a)$ somehow? How can I show this?

Comment: Instead of factoring out a $2p$, try factoring out $a^{2(p-1)}-a^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$a^{2p}\equiv 1\ (\ mod\ n)$$ follows from $$n(a^2-1)=a^{2p}-1$$

We also have $a^{2p}\equiv a^2\ (\ mod\ p)$ due to Fermat's little theorem.
and $$n-1=a^2+a^4+a^6+...+a^{2p-2}=\frac{a^{2p}-a^2}{a^2-1}$$

The numerator is divisible by $p$, but not the denominator (because $p$ does
not divide $a^2-1$). So, $p|n-1$.

Since $n-1$ contains of $p-1$ summands, which are all odd or even, $n-1$ must be
even, so we have $2|n-1$, completing the proof.

This proof shows that there are infinite many Fermat-pseudoprimes to every base $a$.

Comment: Thanks, but I just had a question about where you got the expression $n = 1 + a^2+...$ from?

Comment: Oh very nice thank you! In our course I don't think we're strictly expected to know geometric series, but we do know how to divide polynomials which delivers the same result. Just a background question, are these the pseudoprimes formally known as Carmichael numbers? And they are "pseudoprime" because they are actually composite but satisfy FLT?

Comment: A Carmichael-number must be odd and squarefree and has at least three prime factors. A number $N=p_1...p_n$ with $2<p_1<p_2<...<p_n$ is a Carmichael-number if and only if $p_j-1|N-1$ for $j=1,...,n$.

Comment: Thanks for all your help and for clarifying that!

Comment: I will repeat two of my comments because there were some typos, and I noticed them after the 5-minute-limit : Carmichael numbers have an even stronger property : A number $n$ is a Carmichael-number, if $n$ is a Fermat-pseudoprime to EVERY base $a$ coprime to $n$. In other words, for every $a$ with $(a,n)=1$, the equation $a^{n-1}\equiv 1\ (\ mod\ n\ )$ holds, but $n$ is composite.

Comment: The equation $\frac{a^n-1}{a-1}=1+a+a^2+...+a^{n-1}$ can easily be approved by calculating $a^n-1=(a-1)(a^{n-1}+...+a^2+a+1)$ because nearly all terms cancel out.